# C++ - How to avoid lookup of map entry after replace using [] operator?

Tags: c++, dictionary

How do I prevent having to call .find() on a map after replacing an element in it using the [] operator? (A little background: I am working on a high performance application and in a critical part of the code.) Example:

```
m_Map[key] = value;

... // at this point, I need a reference to the m_Map[key] entry, but I don't want to call the .find() method to get to it.
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `find`?

Comment: I am working on an application where performance is very critical.

Comment: Fine with that, I work in the HPC field too but: - premature optimization is the root of all evil - optimize as a second step and use a profiler to track down the slow parts, that's where you need to optimize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning directly to the result of `[]` operator, store the reference first

```
 DataType &data = m_Map[key];
 data = value;

 // Continue to use `data` here
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I figured but wasn't sure if there was a "better" or more common approach to this...

Comment: @Andrew: if "performance is very critical" you definitely do _not_ want to use this approach as there is an unnecessary default constructed object when using `operator[]()` to insert into the map! You'd use `emplace()` and capture the iterator get a reference from that iterator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl that depends on the data types... for many the inefficiencies should be eliminated by the optimiser, but certainly it's a good point and worth checking, and your suggestion's best if the data types aren't set in stone.

Comment: @TonyD: given that the map implementation will certainly need to add the object in some way, I'd be pretty sure that the use of `emplace()` to insert the element and get hold of the location is never slower but often faster than the use of the subscript operator. That said, I don't have a benchmark ready to prove the point for typical key types.

Answer (score 2):

There's no particular need to separate capturing a reference from the assignment... can be a one-liner unless you find it confusing or think others might:

```
value_type& ref = m_Map[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the [[] operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) returns a reference and even iterators are **not** invalidated, you can simply get away with

```
auto& element = m_Map[key];
element = value;
// use element
```

Second choice: you might use the returned iterator from [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) (best choice if you need to check if the element existed or not)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to the object you just inserted:

```
T& reference = map[key];
reference = value;
```

If you are working on a high performance application you probably don't want to use `operator[]()` anyway as it first default constructs and object (and probably you don't want to use `std::map<...>`, either, but rather `std::unordered_map<...>`). Instead, you'd `emplace()` the object and keep the iterator return from this operation, e.g.:

```
std::unordered_map<K, V>::iterator it = map.emplace(key, value).first;
it->second = other_value;
```